# -AngularJS- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Es mi primera aplicación usando AngularJS del lado del cliente y estoy realizando un dashboard al que previamente el usuario debe acceder "logueandose".

Mi problema no es con el *login*, sino con la forma de recuperar el usuario actual que esta haciendo uso de la aplicación, y al hacerlo como lo estoy haciendo obtengo el error del titulo en un fichero llamado `responsive.js`, lo que no entiendo.

El codigo de error en concreto es el siguiente :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
    at loadPage (responsive.js:32)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (responsive.js:58)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (responsive.js:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.h (responsive.js:2)
loadPage @ responsive.js:32
(anonymous) @ responsive.js:58
dispatch @ responsive.js:2
h @ responsive.js:2
```

En principio tengo un controlador de angular al que llamo cuando la ruta es `/dashboard`, y el acceso a esta ruta privada lo manejo en el login en función de un token de acceso almacenado en DB:

**controllers.js**

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function ($rootScope, $http,localStorageService) {

if(localStorageService.get('token')==null && localStorageService.get('userId')==null){
    $location.url('/');
}
else{

    $http.get('/laURLamiservicio'+localStorageService.get('userId'),
        {headers:{'accept':'application/json','content-type':'application/json','token': localStorageService.get('token')}})
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $rootScope.currentUser = response.data.name;
        })
}
});
```

**index.html**

```
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div ng-controller="userMenuCtrl" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <!-- Right list with user information and logout button-->
  <ul  class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <!-- User drodown -->
    <li ng-show="isUserActive()" class="dropdown ">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
         aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{currentUser}} <span
              class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="">Mi perfil</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="/logout" >Cerrar sesión&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

En este fragmento del fichero **index.html** se puede ver que uso otro controlador que uso para gestionar la visibilidad del nombre del usuario  dentro de un navbar, ayudandome de la directiva **ng-show** que llama a una función **"isUserActive()"** la cual devuelve verdadero o falso en funcion de si el usuario esta logueado o no para mostrar o no el nombre de usuario actual.

Basicamente esto es  lo que quiero conseguir, el problema es que realmente lo muestra correctamente pero al debuggear aparece el maldito error.
¿ A qué se debe?

Comment: Pedro, buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad. Unas preguntas: Podrías poner el error completo? Estás seguro que esa es la función que genera el error? Has probado con la consola de Chrome, ver el stack? PD: Intenta unir todas las preguntas en una sola para facilitar la lectura. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @KN_ . Gracias por tu pronta respuestas. El error completo es:

   `responsive.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
    at loadPage (responsive.js:32)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (responsive.js:58)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (responsive.js:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.h (responsive.js:2)
loadPage @ responsive.js:32
(anonymous) @ responsive.js:58
dispatch @ responsive.js:2
h @ responsive.js:2`

Comment: @KN_ además me he fijado y cuando corro el servidor por primera vez y accedo a la ruta `/dashboard`tras haberme _logueado_ el fallo aparece, pero si vuelvo a acceder a dicha ruta mediante _login_ el fallo no vuelve a aparecer, aunque  haga _logout_ y vuelva a hacer otra vez _login_ .

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente se deba a que en isUserActive() no controlas el caso de que currentUser tenga valor.
ng-show hace que se mire constantemente la función que le pases provocando que mientras que no tengas un valor almacenado, te muestre ese error.

podrias hacer lo siguiente

```
function isUserActive(){
    if(angular.isDefined($rootScope.currentUser)){
       //TU CODIGO
    }else{
       return false;
    }
}
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: He usado `angular.isDefined($rootScope.currentUser)` y aun así me sigue apareciendo. He editado el hilo para detallar mas el problema. Agradecería tu ayuda de nuevo.

Comment: De quien es ese responsive.js? Es de un tercero? En caso de que sea así... de quien es?

Comment: Vale, he descubierto que ese responsive.js es de una extension que usaba de Chrome para probar el diseño en distintas pantallas y resoluciones. 
Lo acabo de desinstalar y en principio ya no me da este problema. Gracias.